# Pexpect Popen_spawn - No output

Tags: python, popen, pexpect

I'm trying to automatise a runas with a prompt of password as bellow

```py
admin_cmd = popen_spawn.PopenSpawn(['runas', '/user:admin', 'cmd'])
admin_cmd.expect('Entrez le mot de passe de admin : ')
admin_cmd.sendline('password')
```

but nothing happen at all anyone got this issue ?

I'm running on 64 bits windows 10 Professional

Answer (score 0):

pexpect.popen_spawn is the windows version of pexpect.spawn. It does not support all features that the spawn class does.  From my experience, interacting with the application (sendline) is not possible on windows.  It is possible through pexpect.spawn on Unix systems (Mac and Linux).

https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows